# Error al correr un ejecutable de Python

Tags: python, pandas

explico cual es mi problema a continuación:
Yo trabajo en Spyder como editor de código para Python, desarrolle un programa que en spyder funciona perfecto, luego si también lo ejecuto desde consola con el comando (py script.py) también funciona, entonces genere un ejecutable con pyinstaller ya que la idea es distribuir el archivo, este ejecutable también me funciono perfecto pero cuando se lo compartí a una persona y no le funciono completamente, hizo el trabajo a medias.

Entonces pregunto si tal vez alguien ha pasado por lo mismo, como soluciono esto?. Ya que en mi pc funciona desde el editor, desde terminal y como ejecutable, pero en un pc externo no hace el trabajo. Agrego que la parte que no funciona uso la libreria Xlsxwritter, no sé si tenga problemas.

Comment: Recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), nosotros no somos adivinos para saber cual es tu código, si no muestras el código cualquier respuesta que te demos será adivinando. Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/478365/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo tu códiga y demás detalles importantes

Comment: Amigo, te comento que como tal no tengo ningún problema con el código, como digo en la explicación, este me funciona a la perfección si lo ejecuto desde Spyder, consola o ejecutable en mi pc, por este motivo considero innecesario agregar el codigo, el problema se da cuando distribuyo el ejecutable a personas que no tienen Python en su pc. Entiendo que no eres adivino, pero también hay que trabajar la compresión lectora. Saludos.

Comment: Tu problema no se puede reproducir por lo que no tendrás una respuesta válida y tu pregunta terminará cerrada

Comment: La respuesta que dieron a continuación esta muy interesante y util, además estoy viendo preguntas similares y en ninguna se agrega código ya que no se necesita. Se te agradece la intención.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor manera para crear ejecutables de Python es utilizando el paquete Pyinstaller.

Lo que hace es generar un .EXE en Windows, un .DMG en MAC o el ejecutable que utilice el sistema operativo. Dentro del ejecutable se incluye el propio intérprete de Python, y por esa razón podremos utilizarlo en cualquier ordenador sin necesidad de instalar Python previamente.

#### Instalación:

La instalación es muy fácil:

Abre tu terminal y ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

No hay más.

#### Primer ejecutable:

Comencemos con algo simple, tenemos un script hola.py:

```
print("Hola mundo!")
```

Y queremos crear un ejecutable a partir de él, pues haríamos lo siguiente:

```
pyinstaller hola.py
```

Una vez acabe el proceso se nos habrán creado varias carpetas. La que nos interesa es dist, y dentro encontraremos una carpeta con el nombre programa y en esta un montón de ficheros y el ejecutable, en mi caso como estoy en Windows es **hola.exe**.

Como es un programa para terminal, para ejecutarlo tengo que abrir la terminal en ese directorio y ejecutar el programa manualmente:

```
C:\Users\Hernando\Desktop\hola\dist\hola>hola.exe
Hola mundo!
```

#### Ejecutable con interfaz:

Ahora vamos a hacer otro a partir de un simple programa con Tkinter, la librería de componentes integrada en Python que ya conocemos. Nos debería funcionar sin problemas:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(text='Hola mundo').pack(pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Suponiendo que lo hemos puesto en el mismo script:

```
pyinstaller hola.py
```

En esta ocasión si ejecutamos el programa con doble clic nos funcionará bien, el problema es que se muestra la terminal de fondo.

Para que desaparezca tenemos que indicar que es una aplicación en ventana, y eso lo hacemos de la siguiente forma al crear el ejecutable:

```
pyinstaller --windowed hola.py
```

#### Ejecutable en un fichero:

Ya véis que por defecto Pyinstaller crea un directorio con un montón de ficheros. Podemos utilizar un comando para generar un solo fichero ejecutable que lo contenga todo, pero este ocupara bastante más:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile hola.py
```

#### Cambiar el icono

También puedes cambiar el icono por defecto del ejecutable. Para ello necesitamos una imagen en formato .ico.

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=./hola.ico hola.py
```

Si por algo no os cambia el icono, probad cambiando el nombre del ejecutable. A veces el caché de Windows puede ignorar estas cosas.

#### Limitaciones:

El gran problema con Pyinstaller son las dependencias.

Si nuestro programa utiliza únicamente módulos de la librería estándard no tendremos ningún problema, pero si queremos utilizar módulos externos es posible que no funcione... A no ser que sea alguno de los soportados como PyQT, django, pandas, matpotlib... pero requieren una configuraciones extra.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, precisamente en mi programa trabajo con Pandas y Xlsxwritter, sabes cuales son las configuraciones adicionales?